# How to calculate matrix (and vector) multiplication with outer product and inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, multilinear-algebra, outer-product

I'm reading a paper "[Multilinear Factorization Machines for Multi-Task Multi-View Learning](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~clu/doc/wsdm17_mfm.pdf)". In section 3.1, there're two equations (7) and (8) I found difficult to understand.

- All vectors are column vectors.
- $\langle·,·\rangle$ denotes inner product. The inner product of matrices or tensors is the sum of the products of corresponding elements, just like the inner product of two vectors.
- $◦$ denotes tensor product (outer product)

Let $e_t$ be the task indicator vector, $e_t=[0,...,0,1,0,...,0]^T$, which is an one-hot encoded vector where only the $t$-th element is 1 and the rest elements are all zeros. So if we have a weight matrix $W$ for all tasks, and $w_t$ is the weight vector for task $t$, then $w_t=We_t$.

The prediction function equation (7) is:
$$f_t(x)=x^Tw_t=x^TWe_t=\langle W,x◦e_t \rangle$$, 
where $x$, $w_t$ and $e_t$ are column vectors, $W$ is a matrix.

> My main question is, **How is the following part derived?**
>
> $x^TWe_t=\langle W,x◦e_t \rangle$

Equation (8) looks similar:
$$f_t(\{x^{(1)}, x^{(2)}\})=x^{(1)^T}W_tx^{(2)}=\langle \mathcal{W}, x^{(1)}◦x^{(2)}◦e_t \rangle$$

> Is it in Eq.(8), $f_t(\{x^{(1)}, x^{(2)}\})$ means $f_t(x^{(1)}◦x^{(2)})$, i.e., the outer product is the input?

Comment: How are you defining the inner product of two matrices?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly writing out $x\circ e_t$ for some small examples? I think you’ll see the pattern for the general case pretty quickly after a few.

Comment: In Section 2.1, `"The inner product of two same-sized tensors X; Y"` is defined. The inner product of matrices or tensors is the sum of the products of corresponding elements, just like the inner product of two vectors.

Comment: Yes, small examples indeed show the equation is true. I'm just wondering if it can be proved using math equations. For two column vectors $a$ and $b$, the inner product is $\langle a,b \rangle = a^Tb=\langle b,a \rangle =b^Ta$; the outer product is $a◦b=ab^T=(b◦a)^T$. I tried to use these two definitions to prove the Eq. (7) but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Don’t require people to chase off-site links for definitions critical to your question. Include immediately relevant context in your question. This site is a Q&A archive. Links go stale and you question could be missing that critical information when someone else looks at it in the future.

Comment: I’m not sure that there’s much to prove here. $x\circ e_t$ has $x$ as its $t$th column and zeros everywhere else. The rest will follow directly from the definition of the inner product, I should imagine.